# Symfony/Less @icon-font-path is undefined in glyphicons.less

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, less

I use Symfony 2.4 and i installed the bundle MopaBootstrap.

less say: NameError: variable @icon-font-path is undefined in glyphicons.less on line 13, column 8. It's a mopabootstrap file.

I extend 'MopaBootstrapBundle::base_initializr.html.twig'. I have no particular code, it's a new project.

Less work great for all my code, except the bootstrap glyphicons file.

Any idea ?

Edit: There is an open issue there if you have some ideas: https://github.com/phiamo/MopaBootstrapBundle/issues/839#issuecomment-39893655

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed 'apply_to: ".less$"' in config.yml and added the less filter to my twig tags. Now assetic:dump --watch seems to work fine.

---

config.yml

```
assetic:
debug:          %kernel.debug%
use_controller: false
filters:
    less:
        node:       /usr/local/bin/node
        node_paths: [/usr/local/lib/node, /usr/local/lib/node_modules]
        apply_to: "\.less$" <<<<< Remove this line
```

---

Base.html.twig

```
{% stylesheets
    '@MopaBootstrapBundle/Resources/public/less/mopabootstrapbundle.less'
    filter='less' <<<<< Add this line
%}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```